# What 80's/90's TV episode has a man escape technology in the countryside, and another hunt him down?

Tags: tv, story-identification

From what I can remember, it was shown somewhere between the mid to late 80's and the early 90's.  I can picture a few scenes and it feels like it should be an 80's Twilight Zone episode (but it isn't). Here's the plot:

A man is surrounded by technology that keeps an eye on everyone (kind of like how real life is right now).  He has a portable phone/beeper device that his boss uses to talk to him, and I believe that his apartment has a wall TV, or it might have been a phone/TV screen combination.

He is fed up with all the technology and wants to escape from it, so he leaves it all behind and travels to the openness of the country (it was a wooded area with a single log cabin-type house).  A man is hired to track him down, and has to do it the old way... since he can't use any technology to track any devices that the man doesn't have on him.

That's all I can remember.  I haven't seen every type of horror/sci-fi TV series ever made (I just found out about a series called "The Darkroom," but I looked over the episodes and it wasn't there), so maybe this does exist?  If not, then it should have.  lol

I have the following on DVD (in various formats) so I know that it isn't an episode from these shows:

- Twilight Zone (80's)
- Outer Limits (90's)
- Monsters (80's)
- Tales From the Darkside (80's)
- Tales From the Crypt (80's)
- Amazing Stories (80's)

Comment: Sounds like a mixture of the film versions of "1984" and "Farenheit 451"

Comment: Also elements of The Pedestrian (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pedestrian). Definitely sounds like Ray Bradbury themes.

Comment: This sounds kind of like the end of Brave New World (the book), but I haven't read it in a while. There were two movies (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080468/ and http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145600/), but neither of them sounds like what you're looking for (or like how I remember the book!). But I haven't seen either--can anyone else say whether they're likely candidates?

Answer (score 2):

Long shot....very very long shot, but it almost sounds like [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_%281985_film%29) with some minor differences.

Tons of technology, man dreams of a countryside home to escape...

Comment: What film or TV show is this *Brazil*? Please could you give a link for reference (e.g. to IMDb, or Wikipedia if it has a page there)?

Comment: Added a link to the film I'm pretty sure dvaeg meant; roll it back, if I'm wrong.  I don't think it's the right answer (Brazil is less against technology, and more against mindless bureaucracy), but thought it at least needed a link :)

Comment: Whoops...I meant to add the link but clicked too fast.   But yes that what's I meant.

Comment: I don't remember any part of Brazil happening outside of the city. I only saw it once when it was released in the 80's though, so I could have forgotten something.

Comment: *Brazil* is somewhat inspired by 1984, and 1984 (the novel, at least) does have the protagonist go to the countryside. I don’t think he’s ever pursued there though.

Comment: Lots of films have men trying to escape to the countryside. There is also _THX 1138_.