# What 80's/90's TV episode had phones built into humans, and a guy who turns his off?

Tags: story-identification

I recall seeing a show back in the 90's, I'm thinking Twilight Zone or Outer Limits as there was no continuity to the series or anything, but I cannot find an episode guide that matches.

It takes place in our near future and in it everybody has a phone type device basically built-in to their body.  They are "plugged in" all the time to instant messaging, calls and emails.

One day this guy is having a terrible day and decides to turn his off for a little while. I recall his wife losing her mind thinking he was dead because he was offline for like 30 minutes and I was hoping to find this episode as it has started to become somewhat prophetic in this day and age.

Anyway, I don't know if this scene was even a major plot point so I have had zero luck finding this but if anyone out there knows what I'm talking about please let me know.

It might even be the same as this unresolved post:
[What 80's/90's TV episode has a man escape technology in the countryside, and another hunt him down?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/tv-episode-from-80s-or-90s)

Comment: This isn't it but the story you mentioned reminded me of the ep, _Stream Of Consciousness_, from the 1990's [The Outer Limits](http://www.imdb.com/video/hulu/vi2220819225) series.

Answer (score 7):

The constant frenetic phones and "plugged in communication" reminds me a little bit of the Ray Bradbury Theater Episode "Murderer" from July 1990 based on the short story of the same name. The series shares some of the same type of interesting twists as Outer Limits and the Twilight Zone series, but doesn't seem to be as widely known.

In it the psychiatrist who goes to the asylum to treat a patient becomes disconnected from the world, thus his wife is worried about him and thinks something has happened to him. However, instead, when he gets out

> the psychologist returns to his office and, barraged by noise and electronics, destroys his newly replaced "lapel phone" and asks his secretary for a chocolate milkshake (to pour into his fax machine).

[IMDB Link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0683226/)

[Wiki Link to Short Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Murderer)

"A psychiatrist is summoned to a prison to interview Albert Brock, a respectable businessman who went on a murderous rampage--against phones, computers, music players, and all the other electronic devices that fill the world with ceaseless noise and distraction. "

[Streaming Link for 1st part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBF1FHiZeXY)

Comment: That might be it! I'll give it a view and let you know.
Thanks!